# Extract new keys from .yml file using Ruby and git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I have a Rails project with a `.yml` file containing I18n translation keys. I want to create a rake task (or similar) which extracts the paths for added keys (lines git recognizes as added). It doesn't matter if the result is being written to the terminal or a file.

Example .yml file:

```
en:
  index: # <-- new key
    greeting: "Hello world!" # <-- new key
  show:
    title: "Old text"
    body: "This is a text" # <-- new key
```

Example output/result of rake task:

```
en.index.greeting
en.show.body
```

Is this somehow possible? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is definitely possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. This function will print all of I18n keys

```
def print_translations(prefix, x)
  if x.is_a? Hash
    prefix += "." if prefix.present?
    x.each do |key, value|
      print_translations(prefix + key.to_s, value)
    end
  else
    puts prefix
  end
end

I18n.translate(:foo)
translations_hash = I18n.backend.send :translations
print_translations "", translations_hash
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Does this print the keys or the strings associated with them?

Comment: Did you mean the value of key like `en.index.greeting: "Hello world!"`?

Comment: Yes - I'm unsure if your answer renders the key's value or the keys themselves? (What I need is the key, not the value.)

Comment: It is return the keys themselves. You can try it on your consolse.